# Sping mvc app - What causes request mapping to not be found?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/BigData/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
```

The error above. I am running into this bug were the request mapping can not be found. I have the index.jsp page loaded but soon as I click the form to submit it can't find the correct place to map the next view loaded.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="/resources/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Big Data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Hint: user and password is "admin", no quotes.</h3>
    <form action="hello" method="post">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br /> Password:<input
            type="password" name="password" /><br /> <input type="submit"
            value="login" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the controller
    package com.bigdata.controllers;

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse res) {  
        String name=request.getParameter("name");  
        String password=request.getParameter("password");  

        if(password.equals("admin")&&name.equals("admin")){  
            String message = "Welcome "+ name;  
            return new ModelAndView("homepage", "message", message);  
        }  
        else{  
            return new ModelAndView("errorpage", "message","Sorry, username or password error");  
        }  

    }  
}
```

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="2.5"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"> 

 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

This is HelloWeb-servlet.xm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bigdata.controllers"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>    
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/**" />  
</beans>
```

Not sure what I am missing but when I start the app I get the form and home page but soon as I enter I get the 404 no mapping found.

Comment: what's the URL of your original request? your `<url-pattern>` seems to target only the root context (i.e. `/`) but your controller seems to be expecting an URI of `/hello` yet the error message refers to `/BigData/hello`

Comment: Where would I find the original url? I am new to spring trying to figure out the work flow of this.  Maybe I am missing a configuration?

Comment: if you are starting with a hello world project, you can follow this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ (hint: you won't need to define your controller/servlet in `web.xml`)

Comment: The original url is like this http://localhost:8080/BigData/

Comment: Sorry mate, I got busy at work... I'll try to look at this issue later on ...

Comment: Much appreciated, I will try this again at home, I just need better spring practice, there is so many crappy tutorials of poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your configuration. Created a sample project with the structure as follows.

[image]

Added a sample method in the HelloWorldController to show the index page

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index(){
  return "index";
}
```

Sample homepage.jsp

```
...
<body>
My Home
</body>
</html>
```

It seems to be working.

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: I thought in spring the index.jsp is required to go in WEB-INF/ not WEB-INF/jsp with all the other views? When I move my index.jso in with all the other views I don't see the homepage anymore.

Comment: I found my issue, a very picky one, it was because my web.xml had extra white spaces so I hack spaced everything over to the left and left it.It is working fine now.